# Force.com System.CalloutException: DER input, Integer tag error

Tags: apex-code, force.com

I am trying to make a callout to a third party service, but I am receiving the message "System.CalloutException: DER input, Integer tag."  The third party has provided us with a self-signed client certificate to use.  I see indications out there (e.g. [here](http://krishhari.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/making-authenticated-web-service-callouts-from-salesforce-to-ibm-cast-iron-using-sslcertificatespart-iv/) and in the [APEX documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_client_certs_http.htm) that this may be possible using a 'legacy' method with setClientCertificate, though I realize these are SOAP examples, which I'm not using.

I have converted the certificate to Base64.  My code is below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();    
req.setEndpoint('https://myurl');
req.setMethod('POST');

string cert = 'mybase64encodedcert';
string certpass = 'mycertpass';

req.setClientCertificate(cert,certpass);

string thebody = 'somebody';
req.setBody(thebody);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

BTW, I have read the APEX docs on Client Certificates and all of the referenced material. I don't think I'm doing something that's covered in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making was that I had encoded the public key only, and was using that in setClientCertificate.  What I needed to do was to base64 encode the entire pfx file, then use that as the cert string:

openssl base64 -in input.pfx -out outputfile.txt

I found the answer [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/apex/message-id/65729/print-single-message/false/page/1).